# Story with a miniature solar system

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

This was in a sample/preview chapter from another book that the publisher included at the end of something else, so I don't have much to go on, but here are the elements I recall -

- the characters lived in free fall in open space, with no need of environment suits.
- everything was in orbit around a **very** small sun, not very far away.
- unclear if breathable atmosphere extended to the sun, or was confined to a ring.
- the level of technology at hand seemed to be pre-industrial.
- the physical constants of the universe were different so that such a small sun could exist.
- material resources were running out, which seemed to imply the necessity of interstellar travel.
- I dimly recall something about coal or carbon being prominent.

The setup is similar in some respects to Larry Niven's *Integral Trees*, but it's definitely not that. In *Integral Trees*, the habitable spaces was a gas torus around some kind of ordinary collapsed star, but in this unknown work, the system center was a miniature sun which required a physically different universe altogether.

I'd like to read it, but I'm not sure I even still have the paperback that had that preview in it. Name that book, please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That sounds a lot like [*Raft*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raft_%28novel%29) by Stephen Baxter. It's technically one of the [Xeelee sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeelee_Sequence), but it stands entirely alone.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like Sun of Suns, by Karl Schroeder.  It was included as a free ebook giveaway by Tor when they launched their site a few years ago, which could be where you picked it up.

The main difference to your description is that there are *several* suns of varying sizes (although all small) within the atmospheric envelope. The plot involves stealing advanced technology from the central sun in order to start up a new one in the outskirts.

Comment: *Sun of Suns* doesn't have different physical constants or problems with resource depletion. And Virga isn't _very_ small.

Comment: I think it's the other book, but anyway, this sounds interesting and is going on my reading list too. Thanks!